# Getting ID from mysql database and echoing the results of that id with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

My question is a bit complicated, so don't get mad if I'm simplifying. So, when a user logs in, I take them to a page showing them information about their account. My question is how do I get their ID and display ONLY their account information, not other people's account. Here is some code:

```
$sql = "SELECT xp, level, coins, stage FROM users";
```

So, I want to get their ID and basically echo out their XP, level, coins, and stage. Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause in your SQL statement.

Comment: you need a WHERE clause in that query, for which you need to have the value of a field in the table at hand to use with the WHERE. For example if you log a user in, you shall perhaps have their username to use like: `WHERE username = $username`. Do not directly inject the user input into the query like that though, look into prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I recommend you use Prepared statements, this will beef up your security. [As per PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples):

```
<?php 
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = 'SELECT id, xp, level, coins, stage FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1'
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $sql )) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); # "i" because your id is probably an int

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

That will query the database only for the specific record of the current user ID... Note, I do not know how you are storing the id, so I just put in the `$_SESSION` variable, just change it to however you do it.

Comment: if you want to concanate, simply use single quotes. If you want to use double quotes, you don't need to concanate.

Comment: Never build SQL strings with concatenation. Use prepared statements with bound parameters.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I don't... He was asking for a simple method... I was just giving him the simplest way to get the user based on the ID

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! No errors, but how do I start echoing out the XP, level, coins, and stage?

Comment: @bob just bind the parameters, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php read the manual for more information